# WordPress FlexSlider is not a function (CTRL + F5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, flexslider

I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function(anonymous function) 
     @ scripts.js?ver=1:87f.event.dispatch 
     @ jquery.min.js:3f.event.add.h.handle.i 
     @ jquery.min.js:3
```

When i CTRL + F5 the page several times, it works, but when you F5 the page it stops working, it's hit and miss at the moment. I've tried updating the flex slider to the latest version but no luck at all. I'm trying to load in the testimonials.

Site: [Website Link](http://bit.ly/1PcVGZp)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're using `wp_enqueue_script` to load your script. Try to force it to load the script (`jquery.flexslider.js`) in header and not in footer.

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>
```

Comment: where would i find wp_enqueue_script? the theme function file?

Comment: probably yes... it depends of how theme is made, i can't tell you exactly where that line is located.

Comment: guessing the line would be impossible haha! Thank you for the pointers, definitely have enough here to get my teeth in to and start debugging the issue.